# Maven build downloading wrongly from central repo

Tags: maven, maven-3, opendaylight

I am trying to build https://github.com/opendaylight/mdsal.git on a local development machine.

The build is failing at:

```
[INFO] features4-mdsal .................................... SUCCESS [  1.315 s]
[INFO] features-mdsal-aggregator .......................... FAILURE [  0.164 s]
The reason being:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:site (generate-site) on project features-mdsal-aggregator: Execution generate-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:site failed: Unable to read local module POM: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.8-odl or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.8-odl in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @
```

The reason is, karaf-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.8-odl is being attempted to be downloaded wrongly from 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

Its actually present in https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/. I have taken care of using the right settings.xml from the recommended url:
    https://github.com/opendaylight/odlparent/blob/master/settings.xml.
    I have placed it as ~/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Try to build again with "-u". Also try to erase your local repository and build again.

Comment: Can you please share your `settings.xml`? (or did you just copy it as-is from the given link)?

Comment: The real problem seems to be that Maven is not seeing the extra repository with this dependency. So indeed, share that settings.xml because you must have made a simple mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue with the Maven site plugin; it will be fixed as soon as Karaf 4.0.9 is released. In the mean time, you can build locally with `-Dmaven.site.skip=true` to avoid the problem entirely.